# (C#) How to close excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to get some datas from an excel worksheet.
I'm using this code:

```
string excelFinalPath = @"C:\Users\fra31\source\repos\Key Visor\Key Visor\Foglio1.xls";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(excelFinalPath);


        Worksheet worksheet = workBook.Worksheets[1];
        object tag = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value;
        MessageBox.Show(tag.ToString());

workBook.Close(true, excelFinalPath, null);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
```

but when I open the excel workbook it's not editable.
I've read it happens because I'm using multiple dots, but i don't understand where.
Can someone help me to understand what I should change?

Comment: You could use `OleDb` and create a connection to the Excel file and then read it into a `DataTable` instead

Comment: @Symon when using OleDb connection you are limited to pure data manipulation. When working with interops you are able to do much more different things, like creating charts, updating formats etc. etc.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki , That's also very true. Which is why I wasn't submitting it as the answer, but rather as a comment. Using `OleDb` can close the connection automagically instead of having to be manual. Just another way to do it

Comment: @Symon on the one side you are right, on the other side a connection is something completely different than an application interop, let's agree that both of them have their intended use cases which are mostly completely different from each other. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.Quit();` does the job.